# Java Strings and UDP headers

Tags: java

1 ) suppose i have a string
str = "some header text used in the protocols";
now with java DataGram class and socket class when i convert this string into byte[] and send it this string will become the body part of the datagram.
how can i make this String header part ?

2 ) i want to use sip protocol without using API. by default URL class uses http and tcp protocol. Datagram uses UDP as a transport protocol. 
suppose i have to contact sip:12345@example.com
example.com is a server that furthers processes. i have few questions.
i)in URL we give address like this www.example.com but i need to have the url in sip format. how to resolve this.?
ii)if i prepare a the the string in this format
str = "INVITE  SIP 2.0
FROM abcd
VIA etc"
will this be considered as an SIP packet or an HTTP packet.? if http packet then how to convert it into SIP packet ?

again ... i dont wanna use any API......
Thank you genius men.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of things.

First of all, forget URL and think [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) instead. And a URI has a *scheme*. In `https://stackoverflow.com` for instance, the URI is `https`. In `file:/tmp/foo`, the URI is `file`. Nothing requires a URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) to go over a network in any way, shape of form.

Then you have the definition of protocols, such as HTTP, FTP, SIP and so on; those protocols, registered to the **IANA** (*Internet Assigned Numbers Authority*, although "Numbers" is an imprecise definition here), define the *transport protocol(s)* over which they communicate (TCP, UDP, or more recently SCTP) along with, when applicable, the *port* (this is how you know, for instance, that SSH communicates over TCP on port 22).

You talk about SIP; it is [defined by an RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261); and this RFC fully defines that SIP is not tied to any transport protocol. From the abstract:

> SIP runs on top of several different transport protocols.

Read the RFC. It's long. But it's worth it. Every bit of it, every character of it.

Comment: i value ur answer friend. i have read RFC article. my question about string . can u answer that please ?

Comment: secndly can u give me one line of code for URI to just give me a push . Thank you.

Comment: I mean it; read the RFC first. It may help you clear up your understanding about HTTP vs SIP etc. HTTP is not TCP! Despite all efforts of many people out there to make it appear so.